# Swiftlint warning : For Where Violation: `where` clauses are preferred over a single `if` inside a `for`. (for_where)

Tags: swift3, xcode8, swiftlint

I am using swift for my application development and using Swift lint. But I am getting a warning regarding the following code:

```
for settingsKeys in searchResults {

        if  settingsKeys.key == settingsObject.key {
          settingsKeys.value = settingsObject.value
          try context.save()
        }
      }
```

The screenshot is attached hereby:

[image]

No automatic fix option is available, so how do I eliminate this warning?

Comment: What is the question here?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

The syntax preferred by your swiftlint configuration is:

```
for settingsKeys in searchResults where settingsKeys.key == settingsObject.key {
    settingsKeys.value = settingsObject.value
    try context.save()
}
```

Which is the similar to

```
for settingsKeys in (searchResults.filter { $0.key == settingsObject.key }) {
    settingsKeys.value = settingsObject.value
    try context.save()
}
```

If you know there is only one result with the same `key`, you might directly use

```
if let settingsKeys = (searchResults.first { $0.key == settingsObject.key }) {
    settingsKeys.value = settingsObject.value
    try context.save()
}
```

Comment: If you want the same behaviour using filter, you'll need `.lazy.filter`

Comment: @Alexander True, didn't want to go into such details.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like it's expecting the `where` to be part of the `for`…

```
for settingsKeys in searchResults where settingsKeys.key == settingsObject.key {
    settingsKeys.value = settingsObject.value
    try context.save()
}
```